IRC calculation shows a maximum in one direction
I am doing IRC calculations on transition-states of organometallic compounds with ORCA. While I only find one imaginary mode for the transition state which corresponds to the expected vibration, subsequent IRC calculations lead to odd results.
In detail, I observe an increased energy along the reaction coordinate either in forward or backward direction (depending on the chosen transition state). My understanding is that for a TS the energy should decrease in both directions.
See below for an example of a trajectory obtained in the IRC calculation. The forward and backward directions are inverted, which I assume is not necessarily a problem. The actual TS is structure 20. The optimized product resulting from the transition state is about 50 kJ/mol lower in energy as the TS, while the educt is about 100 kJ/mol lower in energy compared to the TS.
I use r2scan-3c as DFT method, could this the culprit in this particular application? When I do IRC with the same method on a simple organic decarboxylation reaction, the IRC trajectory looks fine.
ORCA Input
! R2SCAN-3C IRC
%PAL NPROCS 48 END
%maxcore 3000
%irc
  MaxIter 20
  PrintLevel 1
  InitHess Read
  Hess_Filename "new_ts.ts.freq.hess"
end

* xyzfile 1 1 new_ts.ts.xyz



